# connecting teensy + A4988 carrier + motor

Tags: driver, teensy

I am very new to electronics and I am trying to wire a teensy 3.2 to a A4988 driver carrier and a (unipolar???) motor.

I have zero clue what I am doing but I am trying my best to follow the diagram but I am lost on where to connect all of this!? could someone tell me what pins (and why) to get all of this connected so I can then program the teensy to move the motor. I can program, but I am a massive circuit noob. There are too many lines on this diagram for me to understand what is happening

Is this diagram suggesting I need 2 power supplies?

[image: Diagram from driver carrier manufacturer]
[image: Carrier to motor]
[image: My pins]

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right kind of motor? the schematic is for a stepper, the photo is a brushed DC motor

Comment: yea im using a brushed, was hoping I could work it out for a slight modification... no idea though, did not think id struggle so much with such a simple thing

Answer (score 2):

From the photos it appears that you are trying to drive a DC brushed motor (2-wires) using a stepper motor driver chip/breakout.  This could maybe work in a limited way if you hooked up the two motor leads to one of the phase outputs (e.g. 1A and 1B), but pulsing the step input line will not work the way you expect.  You will get a constant current from the one phase if it is enabled but no current when it tries to drive the other phase (that does not exist). In short, either get a stepper or drive your DC brushed motor with an appropriate driver chip (H-bridge with some control input).

Comment: what limited way? Im trying to make an automatic chicken door for my chickens.. so all I need is it to turn to pull the rope and to turn to slack on the rope

Comment: If you just need a constant velocity in one direction and the DC brushed motor you have can provide the torque needed, then you just need a suitable power source and switch capable of switching the current on and off.  A regulated voltage source of whatever voltage the motor is rated for and a FET used as a switch would be suitable for on  / off control via a microcontroller